# Why is my form input not working in laravel database?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to edit my database but my form inputs are not being detected

Here is my form

```html
    <form action="{{ url('update', $user->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <input type="text" name="user_name" class="edit-username" value="{{ auth()->user()->user_name }}">
        <input type="text" name="first_name" class="edit-firstname" value="{{ auth()->user()->first_name }}">
        <input type="text" name="last_name" class="edit-lastname" value="{{ auth()->user()->last_name }}">
        <input type="text" name="password" class="edit-password" value="{{ auth()->user()->password }}">
        <input type="text" name="address" class="edit-address-2" value="{{ auth()->user()->address }}">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="edit-email" value="{{ auth()->user()->email}}">
        <input type="number" name="phone_number" class="edit-number" value="{{ auth()->user()->phone_number }}">
        <input type="submit" class="submit-btn-2" value="edit">
    </form>
    @endif
```

Here is my controller update

```php
    public function update(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'user_name' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'address' => 'required',
            'phone_number' => 'required|min:8|max:11'
        ]);

        $user->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('profile')
                          ->with('success', 'Congratulations! Profile Updated');  
    }
```

The route looks like this

```php
Route::post('update', [UserController::class, 'update']);
```

All the inputs are in the User model fillable bracket

Comment: Form needs a name; `$request->all()` update is dangerous; you can't display hashed passwords as `auth()->user()->password`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I believe you need to specify a variable in the route for receiving the user id. `Route::post('update/{user}', [UserController::class, 'update']);` See https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I'll try those now

Answer (score 0):

in your routing set route update into

```
Route::post('update/{user_id}', [UserController::class, 'update']);
```

or using route::resource

```
Route::resource('user', UserController::class);
```

Read in https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers

get your $user_id in your controller and user findOrFail then update, try this code:

```
public function update($user_id, Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'user_name' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'address' => 'required',
            'phone_number' => 'required|min:8|max:11'
        ]);

        $user->findOrFail($user_id)->update(request()->all());

        return redirect()->route('profile')
                          ->with('success', 'Congratulations! Profile Updated');  
    }
```